# azure sentinel for multiple azure ad tenants

Tags: azure, entra-id

Is it possible to connect azure sentinel for multiple azure ad tenants, so we can control and audit a different directory, which is not under the tenanted generated by sentinel workspace ?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this moment but with the release of Azure Lighthouse it’s only a matter of time before you can use Sentinel with other tenants.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/lighthouse/overview